# Linear constraint considering binary bit position

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

Right now, I have some binary variables for a linear programming problem:

$x_1\;x_2\;x_3\;x_4\;x_5\;x_6\;x_7\;x_8$

Say these are groups of 4 bits each in this example. So:

Group 1 ={$x_1\;x_2\;x_3\;x_4$}

Group 2={$x_5\;x_6\;x_7\;x_8$}

I want to ascertain that any $(a>=)2$ or more bits of the leftmost $(b=)3$ bits (i.e., $x_1,x_2,x_3$) of group 1 must be $0$, and these corresponding bits of group 2 must be $1$.

So the solution set should be:

Group 1 ={$0\;0\;1\;d$} or {$0\;1\;0\;d$} or {$1\;0\;0\;d$} or {$0\;0\;0\;d$}

Group 2={$1\;1\;d\;d$} or {$1\;d\;1\;d$} or {$d\;1\;1\;d$} or {$1\;1\;1\;d$}, where $d$ represents don't care bits, i.e., 0 or 1.

By this, I mean that if $001d$ is a solution for group 1 then $11dd$ is the correct solution for group 2...and three other possibilities as above.

$a$ and $b$ can vary.

Is there any linear constraint for this? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a total rewrite of my solution, based on changes to the original question.

Let $n$ be the number of bits in a group (4 in the original question), $b\le n$ the number of initial bits that are constrained (3 in the original question), and $a \le b$ the minimum number of 0 values among the initial $b$ bits (2 in the original question). I am assuming that, within any one problem instance, $a$, $b$ and $n$ are fixed (but could change from one problem instance to the next).

The following constraints do the job:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^b x_i & \le b - a\\
x_{i + n} & \ge 1 - x_{i} \quad \forall i=1,\dots,b.
\end{align*}

The first constraint ensures that at least $a$ out of the first $b$ bits in the first group are set to 0. The second set of constraints specifies that among the first $b$ bits in each group, if the bit in the first group is 0 then the corresponding bit in the second group must be 1. If the bit in the first group is 1, the corresponding bit in the second group could be either 0 or 1.

No new variables are required.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to follow your procedure mostly. I edited the question a bit. I think you exemplified "any $2$ **or more** bits of the leftmost $3$ bits of group 1 must be 0, and these corresponding bits of group 2 must be 1" in the first line of your answer. In that case, if $0\;0\;d\;d$ is a solution for group 1 then $1\;1\;d\;d$ is the solution of group 2. In this way, we have 3 other possibilities as seen in my question. Sorry for not explaining clearly. Do you think the constraints would remain the same? May I ask you to elaborate on the 'if constraint' a bit? Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, I want to allow each of the 4 possibilities mentioned in the question for group 1 and correspondingly for group 2.

Comment: Are you saying that every 0 in the first three bits of the first group must be matched by a 1 in the same bit of the second group, even if all three of the firs three bits of the first group are 0?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you. More examples can be if $a>=2$ in $b=3$ in $5$ bits, which means we don't care about $x_4, x_5$ bit positions. So the only valid possibilities of the groups are:  if group 1 = {$0\;0\;d\;d\;d$} then group 2 ={$1\;1\;d\;d\;d$}, if group 1 = {$0\;d\;0\;d\;d$} then group 2 ={$1\;d\;1\;d\;d$}, if group 1 = {$d\;0\;0\;d\;d$} then group 2 ={$d\;1\;1\;d\;d$}, if group 1 = {$0\;0\;0\;d\;d$} then group 2 ={$1\;1\;1\;d\;d$}.

Comment: You just said [0 0 d d d] => [1 1 d d d] and [0 0 0 d d] => [1 1 1 d d]. Suppose the first group is [0 0 0 1 0]. The first of those rules allows group 2 to be [1 1 0 0 0] (third bit 0) but the second rule does not. This is inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly. The value of $a$ will vary between 2 and 3 (dependent on the number of $0$s in $b$ of group 1). If the 1st group is [0 0 0 1 0] then group 2 must be [1 1 1 d d] as $a$ becomes $3$ then. That is what I meant by $a>=2$, so maximum (a)= b.

Comment: So your statement that (two comments back) that "if group 1 = {$0\;0\;d\;d\;d$} then group 2 = {$1\;1\;d\;d\;d$}" is incorrect, because the first $d$ in group 1 is not a "don't care" bit, in that if it is 0 then $a$ becomes 3 and the corresponding bit of group 2 must be a 1? Is $b$ fixed, or does that vary as well?

Comment: Yes. Apologies. I updated the question. if group 1 = {0 0 1 d d} then group 2 = {1 1 d d d}". $b$ can also change. For some problems, I might need to consider leftmost 3 bits and some other problems leftmost 4 bits of maybe total 5 bits.

Comment: Thank you a lot. So the equations will be $x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 1$ , $x_5 \geq 1-x_1$, $x_6 \geq 1-x_2$,  $x_7 \geq 1-x_3$? if $b=3$,$a=2$ and $n=4$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The first constraint ensures that **at least** $a$ out of the first $b$ bits in the first group are set to 0. That means (when $b=3$) both $a=2$ and $a=3$ are acceptable in this constraint right? I mean just by putting in $a=2$, am I also saying $a$ can be both $2$ and $3$?

Comment: Yes, it means at least $a$.

Comment: If I want : The first constraint to ensure that at least a out of the first b bits in the first group are set to 1. The second set of constraints to specify that among the first b bits in each group, if the bit in the first group is 1 then the corresponding bit in the second group must be 0. If the bit in the first group is 0, the corresponding bit in the second group could be either 0 or 1. Then are these correct? :
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^b x_i & \le 1-b - a\\
x_{i + n} & \ge 1 - x_{i} \quad \forall i=1,\dots,b.
\end{align*} i.e., the 2nd equation doesn't change.

Comment: Sorry, I think the first equation should be something like: 
\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^b x_i & \le a-b   \end{align*} but not sure...

Comment: No, both are wrong. In the second one, $a-b < 0$, so you have the sum of bits being negative. :-(

Comment: Just replace $x_i$ with $1-x_i$ everywhere in my solution.

Comment: so the solutions will be :
\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^b 1-x_i & \le b - a\\ x_{i + n} & \ge  x_{i} \quad \forall i=1,\dots,b. \end{align*} Are they correct now?

Comment: Put parentheses around $1-x_i$ and the first is correct. The second is still wrong.

Comment: Sorry. I Just replaced $x_i$ with $1-x_i$ and it leaves only $x_i$ in the Right-hand side of the second equation. What would be the correct solution, please?

Comment: \begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^b (1-x_i) & \le b - a\\ x_{i + n} & \ge  x_{i} \quad \forall i=1,\dots,b. \end{align*}

Comment: Please help! Please help!