# Establish constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints, binary-programming

This question is based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4313692/linear-constraint-considering-binary-bit-position/4314531?noredirect=1#comment9062934_4314531). There are two equations given as solutions by prubin.

However, now I want something different. I want the first constraint to ensure that at least $a$ out of the first $b$ bits in the first group are set to $1$, instead of $0$. The second set of constraints to specify that among the first $b$ bits in each group, if the bit in the first group is $1$ then the corresponding bit in the second group must be $0$. If the bit in the first group is $0$, the corresponding bit in the second group could be either $0$ or $1$. I have these equations as possible solutions (as suggested by prubin in the comments):
\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^b (1-x_i) & \le b - a\\ x_{i + n} & \ge  x_{i} \quad \forall i=1,\dots,b. \end{align*}

Are these constraints correct? I believe the answer is given by @prubin in the last thread at the very end but I still can't figure it out. I believe the first equation is correct now but not the second equation. Please help.

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: The solution proposed by prubin was "Just replace $x_i$ with $1−x_i$"; I am not sure what the second equation then becomes as there is already a $1−x_i$" in the original solution proposed:  \begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^b x_i & \le b - a\\
x_{i + n} & \ge 1 - x_{i} \quad \forall i=1,\dots,b.
\end{align*}